# Error when I try to add users to AD with my PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've a WindowsServer 2019 virtual machine with VMware Workstation.

I've this data ( they are no sense, it's just for a test ) :

```
firstname;lastname;office;password;departement    
Tim;machin;Paris;test1;direction
    Anais;machine;Lille;test1;direction
    Luc;truc;Lille;test1;traders
    Pauline;bidule;Toulouse;test1;traders
    Jean;lulu;Lille;test1;traders
```

And this Powershell script :

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security'

$users = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\user.csv"

New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Employes" -Path "dc=devensys-poc,dc=lan"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Lille" -Path "ou=Employes,dc=devensys-poc,dc=lan"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Paris" -Path "ou=Employes,dc=devensys-poc,dc=lan"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Toulouse" -Path "ou=Employes,dc=devensys-poc,dc=lan"

foreach ($user in $users){

    $name = $user.firstname + " " + $user.lastname
    $fname = $user.firstname
    $lname = $user.lastname
    $login = $user.firstname + "." + $user.lastname
    $Uoffice = $user.office
    $Upassword = $user.password
    $dept = $user.departement

    switch($user.office){
        "Lille" {$office = "OU=Lille,OU=Employes,DC=devensys-poc,DC=lan"}
        "Paris" {$office = "OU=Paris,OU=Employes,DC=devensys-poc,DC=lan"}
        "Toulouse" {$office = "OU=Toulouse,OU=Employes,DC=devensys-poc,DC=lan"}
        default {$office = $null}
    }

    try {

            New-ADUser -Name $name -SamAccountName $login -UserPrincipalName $login -DisplayName $name -GivenName $fname -Surname $lname -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Upassword -AsPlainText -Force) -City $Uoffice -Path $office -Departement $dept -Enabled $true
            echo "User added : $name"

    } catch{
    echo "User not added : $name "
    }

    }
```

But everytime I try to execute my script, I've these errors:

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit : Le serveur ne souhaite pas traiter la requête
Au caractère C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\script.ps1:6 : 1
+ New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Employes" -Path "dc=devensys-poc,dc=l ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (OU=Employes,dc=devensys-poc,dc=lan:Stri 
   ng) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Mana 
   gement.Commands.NewADOrganizationalUnit

New-ADOrganizationalUnit : Le serveur ne souhaite pas traiter la requête
Au caractère C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\script.ps1:7 : 1
+ New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Lille" -Path "ou=Employes,dc=devensys ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (OU=Lille,ou=Emp...nsys-poc,dc=lan:Strin 
   g) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Mana 
   gement.Commands.NewADOrganizationalUnit

New-ADOrganizationalUnit : Le serveur ne souhaite pas traiter la requête
Au caractère C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\script.ps1:8 : 1
+ New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Paris" -Path "ou=Employes,dc=devensys ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (OU=Paris,ou=Emp...nsys-poc,dc=lan:Strin 
   g) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Mana 
   gement.Commands.NewADOrganizationalUnit

New-ADOrganizationalUnit : Le serveur ne souhaite pas traiter la requête
Au caractère C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\script.ps1:9 : 1
+ New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Toulouse" -Path "ou=Employes,dc=deven ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (OU=Toulouse,ou=...nsys-poc,dc=lan:Strin 
   g) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Mana 
   gement.Commands.NewADOrganizationalUnit

User not added : Tim machin
User not added : Anais machine  
User not added : Luc truc  
User not added : Pauline bidule
User not added : Jean lulu
```

And I don't know why... Do you have any idea where are my mistakes ? I'm beginner with PowerShell !

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: how are  you importing the data? you don't show the prop names ... so there is no reliable way to associate the sample data with anything. [*grin*]

Comment: @GabrielLuci I've edited my post.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey with the line $users = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\user.csv" ?

Comment: @HK2432 - that won't work with the data you show - there is no header. [*grin*] also, PLEASE don't add info to replies - put it in the Question text.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Oh yes, sorry. I've missed the header. It was added.

Comment: @HK2432 - thank you! that makes things a bit easier to think about.

Comment: @HK2432 - your error `Le serveur ne souhaite pas traiter la requête` translates to `The server does not want to process the request`. that seems to mean that you have a server problem OR a communication problem. **_if you run one such line in your console, does it work correctly?_**

Answer (score 0):

This error in AD is very frustrating and can only be realized when you experience it.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but `Le serveur ne souhaite pas traiter la requête` is the equivalent of `The server is unwilling to process the request`.

You can possibly get this error by having your `DistinguishedName` not explicitly typed out correctly. To prevent this, I would use the AD module to query it and pass it in as a variable so no mistakes are made.

**I would also make sure that you are on the domain with the computer/server you're running this script from.**

```
$ADDomain = Get-ADDomain
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Employes" -Path "$ADDomain.DistinguishedName"

$OUObject = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Employes"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Lille" -Path "$OUObject.DistinguishedName"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Paris" -Path "$OUObject.DistinguishedName"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Toulouse" -Path "$OUObject.DistinguishedName"
```

Let us know if this resolves your issue!